# Can't get Facebook app to post to stream

Tags: javascript, facebook

Thanks in advance for any help!

I've been trying for awhile now to build an app for my website so users can log into the app and it will track the pages on the site that they view and post these stories to their timeline. I'm using the JS code below on my pages. The app seems to be correctly allowing users to log into the app and all, but it never posts anything to their feed despite having publish_stream set as a permission. Also, when I visit the link to my app incognito, I am just given the option to "Go to App" or "Cancel". And then when I click "Go to App," it goes without requesting any kind of permission. So am I missing some kind of code on my site? I also haven't submitted the app in the App Center. Is this necessary in order to get the app to work?

I really appreciate any help here! I'm new to this so I could really use assistance.

Thank you!
Dan

```
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '1665908668*****',
          status     : true, 
          cookie     : true,
          xfbml      : true,
          oauth      : true,
        });
      };

   (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
       }(document));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The app seems to be correctly allowing users to log into the app and all, but it never posts anything to their feed despite having publish_stream set as a permission.

Your app has to *actively* make a post … see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed

> And then when I click "Go to App," it goes without requesting any kind of permission.

Once again, you have to actively do that if you want it to happen. Or you could try [authenticated referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals), which will prompt the user to give permissions before entering your app in certain scenarios.

Comment: Hi CBroe, would you mind adding me on Skype? I'd really appreciate that! Skype name: deankeen